# Find the probability that the 8th woman to appear is in 17th position.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 25 people, consisting of 15 women and 10 men that are lined up in a random order. Find the probability that 7 women are in position 1 through 16, and a woman in position 17.

How to go about this problem?

Comment: What have you tried? What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: I would approach this by calculating the number of ways that such an arrangement can be made, and dividing that by all the permutations of the 15 women and 10 men. It's also useful to draw a picture. The position 17 is a "break point", as you might imagine.

Comment: Exactly $7$ women or at least $7$ women?

Comment: @drhab it has to be exactly 7 women, as at 17th position the 8th women should appear.

Comment: if you treat the women as indistinguishable, there 7 women and 9 men in the first 16 positions.  How many ways could they be arranged?  Then you have two more sections to arrange people in.  Then you can work out what the total number of ways of standing are - effectively you can treat them as black and white balls (only distinguishable as man or woman)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT:** Choose $1$ woman from $15$ and put her to $17^{th}$ position. Then from the rest of $14$, choose $7$ of them; and from $10$ men choose $9$ of them and permute them in the positions $1-16$. Then, permute the rest of people in the positions $18-25$.

**EDIT:** Just to verify my answer with the other two answers, the answer is
$$\frac{\dbinom{15}{1}\dbinom{14}{7}\dbinom{10}{9}16!8!}{25!} \approx 0.028$$

Comment: I was thinking on the same line of thought, fixing one women I am left with 14 women. Now if I take out 7 women 14c7 I am left with 9  spots filling it with men 10c9. So, there are 14c7*10c9*9!*7! permutations for 1-16 spot?

Comment: It is correct except for $9!7!$ part. Note that women and men are not in predetermined positions so you can also swap positions of a man and a woman.

Comment: From 1-16 spot, I can also have permutation of 16!, arranging those chosen men and women. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that one is right. So, for positions $1-16$, we have $\binom{14}{7}\binom{10}{9}16!$ arrangements. You should also think similarly for the positions $18-25$.

Answer (score 8):

The probability that exactly $7$ of the first $16$ positions are filled with women is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{15}{7}\dbinom{10}{9}}{\dbinom{25}{16}}$$
since we must select $7$ of the $15$ women and $9$ of the $10$ men for the first sixteen positions.  That leaves $8$ women and $1$ man.  Therefore, if exactly seven women have been placed in the first $16$ positions, the probability that a woman is then placed in the $17$th position is $8/9$.  Hence, the probability that the eighth women appears in the $17$th position is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{15}{7}\dbinom{10}{9}}{\dbinom{25}{16}} \cdot \frac{8}{9}$$

Comment: Our outcomes match (relief) ;).

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary to distinguish "by person". Distinguishing "by gender" is enough.

$15$ spots are selected for women out of a total of $25$ spots.

You can think of it as selecting from a basket having exactly $16$ red ball, $1$ blue ball and $8$ yellow balls.

The blue balls correspond with the first $16$ spots, the blue ball with the $17$-th spot and the yellow balls with the last $8$ spots.

By taking without replacement $15$ balls the probability on $7$ red balls, $1$ blue ball and $7$ yellow balls is:

$$\frac{\binom{16}7\binom11\binom{8}7}{\binom{25}{15}}=\frac{\binom{16}7\binom{8}7}{\binom{25}{15}}\approx0.028$$

Comment: Be careful.  You need to select $7$ women and $9$ men for the first $16$, not $15$, positions, then select a woman for the $17$th position.  Also, you meant that red balls correspond with the first $16$ spots.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig But I am selecting $15$ "spots". They are to be distributed to the women. From the first $16$ spots $7$ must be selected, spot $17$ must be selected and from the last $8$ spots again $7$ must be selected. So there are $\binom{16}7\binom11\binom{8}7$ appropriate selections. Still something wrong with this?

Comment: The reason I did not initially follow your argument is that you did not specify that you were selecting $15$ spots for the women, and I had a different method in mind.